# Différence entre "je suis sur + nom ville " et "je suis à + nom ville "

Tags: sens, synonymes

Quelle est la différence entre:
"Je suis à Paris" et "Je suis sur Paris " ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Je suis *sur* Paris

... est une expression à la mode pour dire : *Je suis **à** Paris*.

C'est une expression familière qui hérisse les oreilles des anciens, et donc à ne pas utiliser en langage soutenu :

- *On est **sur** un objet* : sur une chaise, sur les grands boulevards
- *On est **à** ou **dans** un lieu fermé* : à (devant l'Opéra) ou dans l'Opéra (j'y suis entré)
- *On est **à** un nom de ville* : à Paris, à Arles
- *On est **en** un nom de département, de région...* : en Île de France, en Arles (dans le pays d'Arles)

*Être **sur** Paris* voudrait dire que l'on vole au dessus de Paris en hélicoptère (ce qui est interdit. Seuls les services de sécurité, les hélicoptères militaires et officiels peuvent survoler Paris sur des parcours très sécurisés).

La personne qui prononce cette phrase s'imagine probablement être sur une carte où Paris est situé, mais il y a sûrement d'autres explications.

---

*Intégration des commentaires*

*Être **sur** Paris* reviendrait à dire :

> - Je suis *provisoirement à* Paris,
> - Je suis *en déplacement à* Paris,
> - Je suis *dans la même localité* que toi.
> - Je suis *dans une (proche) banlieue de Paris* (souvent accessible par le métro, plus rarement par le RER ?

Comment: You are right about it being used as an expression signifying being geographically in an area, like a tack on a map. 

One of the most common occurrence I have heard and used for "sur" instead of "à" in this context was when the stay was temporary, over a weekend for example (and then it would be told, like "Je suis sur Paris pour le weekend"), or when it implies you just arrived there (give or take a couple hours).

Comment: @Spesiel agree. In fact, saying "Je suis sur Paris" implies that you don't stay long in the city. I'm using it quite often, so I suppose it's common ?

Comment: @GautierC Very common. In fact, I've heard it used that way all my life (I'm 32). It's a sorta idiom, I would say.

Comment: @Spesiel Je reviens sur Paname :p

Comment: J'abonde sur l'aspect provisoire, par exemple: _Le patron d'Airbus est à Toulouse, mais aujourd'hui il est sur Paris_.

Answer (score 3):

Je viens compléter la réponse très pertinente donnée par cl-r par un autre point de vue sur la question.

Je suis une personne qui ne vit pas à Paris.
Si un de mes amis, qui n'est pas Parisien non plus, m'envoyait un message pour me demander où je suis, je lui répondrais *Je suis **à** Paris.*

En revanche si je souhaitais aller voir un de mes amis parisiens, je lui écrirais probablement un message lui disant que *Je suis **sur** Paris*, et que du coup nous pourrions nous voir.

Pour moi la différence se situe au niveau de ce qui est le plus important. Dans le premier cas, où j'utilise ***à*** ce qui compte c'est que je ne suis pas au même endroit que mon ami. Dans le deuxième cas, où j'utilise ***sur*** ce qui compte c'est que je suis dans la même ville que mon ami.

Je ne crois pas qu'il y ait de règle grammaticale, il s'agit effectivement d'une expression récente qui n'est utilisée qu'à l'oral ou presque. Dans le doute, il vaut mieux éviter de l'utiliser car ***à*** marche dans tous les cas.